# How to spawn a collider after exiting a trigger? (Bomberman style game)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I trouble trying to get this to work. here is the problem.

When I spawn I bomb with a collider, it presses my character out of the way, forcing him either in the wall or to a side.

Now my character instantiates a Bomb gameobject with a bomb script.

**What I want and my thought process:**

I was thinking it might be possible having a triggercollider on the instantiated bomb, and no collider, but when my character "leaves" the bomb radius it spawn a regular collider.

Then He can't get stuck, and when he has exited he can't just past through it again.

But I don't know how to write this, any suggestions?

Or any better ideas? Thanks for all help :)

ps: ( I use c#)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost get a solution.
 1. in bomb collider check trigger;
 2. in bomb script at start [get reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) to collider
 3. in [OnTriggerExit](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerExit.html) set isTrigger to false

```
public class bomb : MonoBehaviour {

BoxCollider collider;

void Start () {
    collider = gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider> ();
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    collider.isTrigger = false;

}
```

}

P.S. don't mix 3d and 2d colliders. Code sample for 3d, in 2d it slightly different.

Comment: I still can't get it to work. Its says it hides bomb.collider member. cs0108 warning.

I have a boxcollider2D on the bombprefab with the trigger checked.
Here is the bomb script:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/18420539465be08ff43c

Comment: You should use OnTriggerExit2D.

Comment: Thank you! that worked like a charm! : ) I would vote you, But I don't have the rights yet : P Thanks again : )